# d3.event.path undefined in firefox

Tags: firefox, d3.js, event-propagation

I used d3.js to bind a click event to some svg-elements. I am trying to use d3.event.path to see the propagation path (elements below the clicked position) when an element is clicked.

This works in chrome, but not in firefox (latest version, tried both windows 10, ubuntu 14.04).  Firefox returns undefined.

Any idea how to get the propagation path of a d3 event and firefox ?

```
<div id="test" style='width:200px;height:200px;border:2px solid black'>
</div>

var svg = d3.select('#test')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 200).attr('height', 200);

var r = svg.append('rect')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(50,50)')
    .attr('width', 100).attr('height', 100)
    .style('fill', 'purple');

svg.on('click', function(){
    console.log(d3.event.path);
});
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/a9L9j9j1/  for an example. When clicking the purple rectangle chrome correctly returns an array [rect, svg, div ...  window], but firefox returns undefined.

Thanks!

Comment: Chrome returns a `MouseEvent` for `d3.event` while Firefox returns a `click`. One of these has a `path` attriibute, while the other does not. It looks like you'll need to find a different way to go about getting the propagation path.

Comment: `d3.event.target.parentElement` will give you the parent node (svg in this case). You could write a recursive function (or use a loop) to build a list of the parents until you reach `null` or `window`, as desired.

Comment: `var path = [d3.event.target]; var i = 0; while ((x = path[i++].parentNode) != null) path.push(x);` You can use `parentElement` as well if you don't need the `HTMLDocument` element in the array. This works in both browsers except for getting `window`, which is already a given.

Comment: Thanks, that works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

try to change `this._d3.event.path` with `this._d3.event.composedPath()`